# IF ELSE return wrong value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement

I have a script that need to return the DATETIME from IF ELSE condition. But my return value from this got a wrong value here.

So this is my script

```
DECLARE @last_date SMALLDATETIME;
DECLARE @end_date SMALLDATETIME;
DECLARE @initial_date SMALLDATETIME;
DECLARE @begin_date SMALLDATETIME;
DECLARE @datediff int;
DECLARE @date_day int;

SET @last_date = NULL;
SET @datediff = NULL;
SET @initial_date = NULL;

IF (@datediff = '' or @datediff is NULL)
    SET @datediff = 5;
ELSE
    SET @datediff = @datediff;

IF (@last_date = '' or @last_date is NULL)
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1);
ELSE
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @last_date)-1, -1);

IF (@initial_date = '' or @initial_date is NULL)
    SET @begin_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @end_date)-@datediff, 0);
ELSE
    SET @begin_date = @initial_date;
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @begin_date)+@datediff, DATEPART(d,@initial_date));

print(@begin_date)
print(@end_date)
```

From this logic, it should take a value like this

- begin_date = Dec  1 2020 12:00AM
- end_date = May 31 2021 12:00AM

but it only return value

- begin_date = Dec  1 2020 12:00AM

But from that script why it entered to ELSE condition `@initial_date` ? is there any something wrong from my script ?

Comment: You are setting _SET initial_date = NULL;_ so your initial_date is always null, so you always execute the if part of the if/else. You never get to the ELSE part

Comment: @nacho Uhmm, sorry but why my `@end_date` didn't printed ? I've SET it on my `@last_date` if/else condition ?

Comment: This script has quote a few issues: `''` is not a valid date, nor is it a number, either use `1970-01-01` and `0` respectively, or remove it. `DATEADD` looks like it's got the parameters backwards. The last `ELSE` needs `BEGIN/END`. And looks like you haven't heard of `EOMONTH()` and `DATEFROMPARTS` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the reason for this unexpected result is that the last line (`SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @begin_date) + @datediff, DATEPART(d, @initial_date));`) is outside the `IF.. ELSE` block and always sets the value of `@end_date` to `NULL`. Probably an appropriate `BEIGN .. END` block in the last `IF..ELSE` statement will solve this issue:

```
...
IF (@initial_date = '' or @initial_date is NULL)
    SET @begin_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @end_date)-@datediff, 0);
ELSE BEGIN
    SET @begin_date = @initial_date;
    SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @begin_date)+@datediff, DATEPART(d,@initial_date));
END
```

Comment: So I need to add `BEGIN .. END` to my other `IF .. ELSE` condition ? such as `@begin_date`, and `@last_date` ?

Comment: @RudyTriSaputra, not always. If you execute a single statement, the `BEGIN .. END` language block (a statement block) is not necessary, but is not an error.

Comment: Personally I would recommend always using `BEGIN/END` because you avoid this issue and IMO its easier to be consistent than have a different pattern depending on whether there is 1 statement or multiple inside the `IF`.